# Does immediately ending the turn cause mana burn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When cards such as [Time Stop](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Time%20Stop) or [Sundial of the Infinite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sundial%20of%20the%20Infinite) that immediately end the turn are cast, are players subject to mana burn for excess mana in their mana pools?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the Comprehensive Rules. A lot has changed since fourth edition, including the stack and how damage works.

Comment: The [basic rulebook](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/resources/rules/EN_MTGM14_PrintedRulebook_LR.pdf) does at least generally cover how combat damage works (and is a lot faster to read than the comp rules). There's also [this article](http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/42a) covering the main changes (which happened in Magic 2010) or [this one](http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/46a) with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mana burn does not exist as a rule in MTG anymore. It was removed from the rules when they released the 2010 core set.

[You can read the introduction of the Magic 2010 rules changes here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160120014846/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/42a)

Back when the mana burn rule did exist, Time Stop still would cause a player to lose life due to mana burn. This is because mana burn happened automatically whenever a phase ended, and time stop caused the current phase to end. Mana burn did not use the stack, and was simply an automatic game action that occurred.

Comment: This makes me sad.

Comment: But Braid of Fire is so good now!